# Submit from the angular material form inside dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I have a form inside the dialog box.

`mainComponent`

```
  openDialog() {
     this.dialog.open(ModelContent);
  }
```

`HTML`

```
<form (ngSubmit)="setRule(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <md-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Name" name="name" ngModel>
        </md-form-field>
    .....

      <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close>Confirm</button>
      <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>

</form>
```

I had a form without a dialog box and it was working fine for both `confirm` and `cancel`, now I decided to open the form inside the dialog box. But I cannot get the value of `setRule(f)`.

`ModelComponent`

```
setRule(f) {
  console.log(f);
}
```

Can somebody please let me know what I am missing. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Open Dialog code is added in the same component where setRule() method is defined?. If yes. That should work.

**Service:**

```
private formSubmitEvent = new Subject<any>();
public formSubmitEvent$ = this.formSubmitEvent.asObservable();
```

**Main Component:**

```
setRule(){
   service.formSubmitEvent.next(values);
}
```

**ModelComponent:**

```
ngOninit(){
    service.formSubmitEvent$.subscribe(values=>{
       console.log(values);
    })
}
```

Comment: `setRule()` is in the modelComponent and `openDialog` is in the main component as explained in the angular materail docs

Comment: Then its 2 differnet component. You need to emit the values from main component to modelComponent using Subject/Behavior Subject.